# Spotlight crashes when entering a specific query string

Tags: finder, crash, spotlight

I have a folder on my mac which I access occasionally, let's say its name is `FolderABC`.
I usually hit `CMD + Space` to bring up Spotlight, then type the name into it and it will be the first result.
Recently, Spotlight crashes instead, as soon as I type `Folder` and before typing any more letters. If I type any other query, it works normally. I can tell it crashes since the Loupe icon briefly disappears from the menu bar (Spotlight restarts immediately) and looking in `system.log` in Console shows this, whenever the problem occurs:

```
Oct  4 18:27:21 my-macbook-pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Spotlight[16126]): Service exited due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4 sent by exc handler[0]
```

I'm currently having Spotlight rebuild its index, but what else could I try?
Specifically, are there any debugging tools available to get a more detailed stack trace of what's causing the app to crash?

My OS version is **10.12.6**

Comment: OK ,let me crash my Spotlight, or do you have some special add on to it

Comment: can you look at the mds and mds_stores in your activity monitor (cpu usage) before and after

Comment: `mds_stores` briefly goes from 0 to around 10 while `mds` goes from 0 to about 2. So they are doing _something_.

Comment: that looks normal to me

Comment: something is in your mysterious folder that scares Spotlight

Comment: Well, it's full of bank statement pdfs. As a test I removed all which were added in the last couple of months, but as expected, that doesn't do anything. If anything, the problem should be in the parent directory, no? Why would Spotlight look through the folder contents when I'm searching for the folder itself?

Comment: Does your `FolderABC` or what ever you call it, contains any wild charters ? did you try moving the folder to desktop

Comment: The folder name had an umlaut, but that wasn't a problem before. Since I didn't update the OS it can't be a regression in Spotlight.

Comment: I have now the same problem when typing in `latex`. What the hell is going on here?

Comment: Turns out I'm not the only one experiencing the issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8551847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old answer:**

My first solution was simply reindexing all folders by running

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

This did not help. I then renamed the folder in question, reindexed again, named it back and reindexed another time. The problem has now disappeared.

**Update:**

The bug seems to have been introduced with the update to Safari 12. As discussed in the [apple product forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8546951), a workaround is to **disable `Bookmarks & History` in the Spotlight system preferences**.

Comment: Up-voted for keeping your post updated.